# How do I get the outerHTML of a cloned element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom, element

I'm trying to avoid jQuery, simply needing to clone an element, *e.g.*

```
var table: Node = document.querySelector('#myTable').cloneNode(false);
```

Later, I need to

```
return table.outerHTML;
```

but I'm getting the error

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/overworld-component.tsx:24:43
TS2339: Property 'outerHTML' does not exist on type 'Node'.
```

Which, makes sense. Only `Element`s have `outerHTML`.

What am I supposed to do here?

- Somehow cast `Node` to `Element` since I know it's definitely an `Element`?
- Find some other way to clone the element (without children), but as an element?
- Or, am I doing something wrong further upstream? Maybe I don't need to use `outerHTML` at all? I thought I needed the `outerHTML` in React for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`ing:

  ```
  export class OverworldComponent extends React.Component<OverworldComponentProps, {}> {
      render() {
          var table: Node = document.querySelector('div.file div.data table').cloneNode(false);
          return <div id="overworld-viewer"
                      dangerouslySetInnerHTML=
                          { { __html: table.outerHTML } } />;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about saving the outerHTML directly ?

```
    export class OverworldComponent extends React.Component<OverworldComponentProps, {}> {
        render() {
            var outerHTML: string = document.querySelector('div.file div.data table').outerHTML;
            return <div id="overworld-viewer"
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML=
                            { { __html: outerHTML } } />;
        }
    }
```

or you can cast `cloneNode`:

`var table: Element = document.querySelector('div.file div.data table').cloneNode(false) as Element;`

Comment: The casting worked! I kept trying to cast with `<Element>` in the beginning and that wasn't working. But `as Element` did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify the datatype, Just use 'any'

```
var table: any = document.querySelector('#myTable').cloneNode(false);
```

Or

```
var table: HTMLElement = <any>document.querySelector('#myTable').cloneNode(false);
```